# How to get the output of the code as a list?

Tags: python, linux

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print os.path.join(dirname, filename)
```

Im only able to print the Sub directories. How can get the names of sub-Directories as a list?

Comment: Declare a list to collect the names outside the `for` loop. `append` to that list inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a list to collect the names outside the `for` loop. `append` to that list inside the loop.

```
import os

subdirs = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # collect path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        name = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        subdirs.append(name)

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

print(subdirs)
```